# Java Qpid Proton - ActiveMQ broker Cannot assign requested address: bind

Tags: java, activemq-classic, bind, amqp, qpid

I really need an answer to this question that's why I'm editing it.

I have an Apache ActiveMQ broker built inside my connection using this code

**Broker.java**

public class Broker {

```
private BrokerService broker;

public Broker(String connector) {
    this.broker = new BrokerService();
    this.broker.setUseJmx(true);
    try {
        this.broker.addConnector(connector);

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void addConnector(String connector){
    try {
        this.broker.addConnector(connector);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start() {
    try {
        this.broker.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public BrokerService getBroker() {
    return broker;
}

public void setBroker(BrokerService broker) {
    this.broker = broker;
}
```

}

Here is my problem

I use the Qpid Proton library (available here : [Qpid Proton](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/)). I have one class to read data which is nearly the example they give you on qpid webiste

```
package messaging;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.qpid.proton.Proton;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.amqp.messaging.AmqpValue;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Delivery;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Event;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Receiver;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.message.Message;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.FlowController;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.Handshaker;

public class AMQPSubscriber extends BaseHandler {

    private String broker;
    private String topic;
    private String port;

    public AMQPSubscriber(String broker, String port, String topic) {
        this.broker = broker;
        this.port = port;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.add(new Handshaker());
        this.add(new FlowController());

    }

    @Override
    public void onReactorInit(Event event) {
        try {
            event.getReactor().acceptor(broker, Integer.parseInt(port), new AMQPSubscriber(broker, port, topic));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelivery(Event event) {
        System.out.println("---------Message Received--------");
        Receiver recv = (Receiver) event.getLink();
        Delivery delivery = recv.current();
        if (delivery.isReadable() && !delivery.isPartial()) {
            int size = delivery.pending();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            int read = recv.recv(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            recv.advance();

            Message msg = Proton.message();
            msg.decode(buffer, 0, read);
            System.out.println("Subject : " + msg.getProperties().getSubject());
            System.out.println("Text : " + ((AmqpValue) msg.getBody()).getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

This class is called in the main :

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException{

    Broker broker = new Broker("amqp://" + host + ":" + AMQPport);
    broker.start();

 AMQPSubscriber receiv = new AMQPSubscriber(host, "5672", topic);
        Reactor r;
        try {
            r = Proton.reactor(receiv);
            r.run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

But when i execute this code, i get a

```
 INFO | Loaded the Bouncy Castle security provider.
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Users\alexi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\IOT\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB]
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
 INFO | KahaDB is version 6
 INFO | Recovering from the journal @1:61115
 INFO | Recovery replayed 11 operations from the journal in 0.014 seconds.
 INFO | PListStore:[C:\Users\alexi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\IOT\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.3 (localhost, ID:DESKTOP-UK0JIC4-52783-1467025817901-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://127.0.0.1:5672
 INFO | Connector amqp://127.0.0.1:5672 started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.3 (localhost, ID:DESKTOP-UK0JIC4-52783-1467025817901-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: C:\Users\alexi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\IOT\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB only has 7792 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 7792 mb
 WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: C:\Users\alexi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\IOT\activemq-data\localhost only has 7792 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 7792 mb
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.AcceptorImpl.<init>(AcceptorImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.acceptor(ReactorImpl.java:477)
    at messaging.AMQPSubscriber.onReactorInit(AMQPSubscriber.java:33)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:209)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.delegate(EventImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:114)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:275)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.run(ReactorImpl.java:343)
    at messaging.Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

This broker works fine when I use MQTT and Paho, I would like it also works with AMQP.
I know bind means the port is already used, but I can't figure out how I could listen on a port where no data is sent.

Thanks for helping me.

Alexi

Comment: is `192.168.100.47` supposed to be your local IP? If so, are you *sure*? Also check your `hosts` file to see if there's any entry for `localhost` other than `127.0.0.1`

Comment: This IP is the server address, which is another computer one the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

When i add a connector to the activeMQ embedded broker, it adds it as a TCP which only allows one connection at a time.

So I create a connector as UDP like this :
`broker.addConnector("udp://"+host+":"+AMQPport);`

This solution is working for me I hope it can help other developers in the future.

Cheers, Alexi

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when there is another application that has created a server socket listening on the target port you have requested.  You need to check that you aren't running another broker instance on that port or have some firewall in place that is blocking access.

Comment: I have tried using `netstat -a -n -o | find "5672"`` and when my program is terminated, I have nothing left., I also checked my firewall which allow connections on it. And the only process using this port in my app is my embedded broker which I guess is mandatory for the AMQP transport. I guess the error is somewehere else